# Deadlock in Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, deadlock, c3p0

I have scoured the internet but haven't found anything on below. Please let me know if I have missed anything.

We are experiencing c3po's "Apparent Deadlock" exception in our server. PFB the DAO function:

```
 try{
   criteria = session.createCriteria();
   ....... // restriction et al.
   List<MyObject> myObj = (List<MyObj>) criteria.list();
 }catch(Exception e){ //exception handling }
 }finally{ session.close();  }
```

We started seeing the deadlock exception when we added below code in MyObject.class

```
 public class MyObject{
  ...//member variables and methods
  private Set<CustomClass> variable;

  public void setVariable(Set<CustomClass> variables){
     variables.stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.myFn()
                .compareTo(e2.myFn())); //encountered deadlock exception after adding this line
     this.variables = variables;
  }
 }
```

I removed the sorting code and added an order-by clause in hbm mapping to fix the deadlock exception. 
My question is this - **why would this introduce a deadlock in the first place?**

Thanks!

**Edit:** Corrected typo in code

Comment: How does this compile in the first place? `Stream.sorted()` returns another stream and not a set.

Comment: Wow.  I'm surprised.  I don't see any compilation errors neither was this flagged by our build system.

Comment: Why would you sort a collection and then put the sorted data in a Set? Set is an unordered collection.

Comment: We were forced to use Set association mapping for this object in hbm as a last ditch attempt. I don't quite remember the reason for this but the error message said something like there's enough bag instance.

Comment: Can you print out the object passed in `setVariable(...)`? I'm interested in which implementation of the `Set` interface is passed.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I looked up the code. I made the error of storing stream in set here. Edited the question.

Comment: @JanezKuhar PersistentSet